# No resource found that matches given name in main.xml

Tags: android

This is really starting to drive me crazy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@id+/textview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:text="@string/hello"/>
```

Produces the following error message: "`Error: no resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id+/textview')`.

This is copy and pasted from the Android hello world
[example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html).

Answer (score 25):

`@+id` not `@id+`. Seems the tutorial is wrong!

Comment: I just downloaded the SDK, still buged

Answer (score 8):

It's just a small typo; you need to put the '+' after the '@', not after 'id':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:text="@string/hello"/>
```